# Bootstrap carousel("pause") not working when click on button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on Bootstrap. Everything works fine like carousel (Image Roll full screen), carousel controls both left and right as I need.
The extra thing what I need is that pause button in middle of the carousel.
when i click on 'pause' the carousel should pause until I click on 'Play'.
To do this, I used Jquery.

```
$(".carousel").carousel("pause");
```

However, when I click on btnPause carousel not pausing at all.
Don't know what I am missing.

Complete Code :

### HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel carousel-fade slide">
.
.
.
//Controls
<a class="bgLeft" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
<a class="bgMid" id="btnPause"></a>
<a class="bgRight" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.bgMid {
background: url('/Img/pause.png')no-repeat;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -17px;
```

}

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myCarousel").carousel({
            interval: 5000,
            pause: "false"
        });
        $("#btnPause").on('click', function () {               
            $(".carousel").carousel("pause");
        });
    });
```

Comment: please check http://jsfiddle.net/8jLbf30u/

Comment: Thx for the solution, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
$("#btnPause").on('click', function () {               
    $(".carousel").carousel("pause");
});
```

to

```
$("#btnPause").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".carousel").carousel("pause");
});
```

And than test

Comment: Have a look at link http://jsfiddle.net/XFcSv/478/ and check if you have any different structure is used. Also create your own fiddle as per above data so you your answer can be made easy